# Parallel Tasks In WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, parallel-processing, async-await, task-parallel-library

I'm trying to implement parallel tasks in WPF and it seems like it's not working. I have a very simple app that has one button, one label and it performs the following:

1. The user clicks the button.
2. The label is updated to show that the app is working.
3. Two worker methods are run in parallel. Each worker method accesses a UI element as part of it's algorithm.
4. When the two worker methods are done, the label is updated to show the amount of time it took each to run as well as the overall time of the app to run.

When I run the program, I get the following results:

```
Worker 1 Time: 00:00:00.2370431
Worker 2 Time: 00:00:00.5505538
Total Time: 00:00:00.8334426
```

This leads me to believe that the worker methods are probably running in parallel, but something is blocking the application in a synchronous manner. I'm thinking that the total time should be close to the longest running worker method time if they are truly running in parallel. One gotcha I ran into was that because I'm accessing UI elements in the worker methods, I needed to use the `Dispatcher.Invoke()` method.

Note: I read the documentation on [Task-based Asynchronous Programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609(v=vs.110).aspx#Creating%20and%20running%20tasks%20implicitly). It states, "For greater control over task execution or to return a value from the task, you have to work with Task objects more explicitly." That is why I'm running tasks implicitly; I am not returning anything from the worker methods and I don't need greater control (at least I think I don't).

Am I correct in assuming that the app is running the worker methods in parallel and something is forcing the app to behave in a synchronous manner? Why am I getting the sum of the worker methods' times for the total time?

XAML

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow"
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
        ResizeMode="NoResize"
        Height="150"
        Width="300">
  <StackPanel>
    <Button x:Name="Button1"
              HorizontalAlignment="Center"
              VerticalAlignment="Center"
              Content="Click Me"
              Click="Button1_Click" />
    <Label x:Name="Label1"
           Content=" " />
  </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

C#

```
namespace WpfApp1
{
    using System.Diagnostics;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Windows;
    using System.Windows.Threading;

    public partial class MainWindow
    {
        private string _t1;
        private string _t2;
        private Stopwatch _sw;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private async void Button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            _sw = new Stopwatch();
            _sw.Start();
            Label1.Content = "Working...";

            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                Parallel.Invoke(Work1, Work2);
                Dispatcher.Invoke(UpdateLabel);
            });
        }

        private void UpdateLabel()
        {
            _sw.Stop();
            Label1.Content = $"T1: {_t1}\nT2: {_t2}\nTotal: {_sw.Elapsed}";
        }

        private void Work1()
        {
            Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
            {
                var text = Button1.Content;
                var stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
                stopWatch.Start();
                for (var i = 0; i < 100000000; i++) { }
                _t1 = stopWatch.Elapsed.ToString();
            }, DispatcherPriority.ContextIdle);
        }

        private void Work2()
        {
            Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
            {
                var text = Button1.Content;
                var stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
                stopWatch.Start();
                for (var i = 0; i < 250000000; i++) { }
                _t2 = stopWatch.Elapsed.ToString();
            }, DispatcherPriority.ContextIdle);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're Scheduling a thread pool thread to have it schedule two thread pool threads that both just ask the UI thread to do a bunch of work, having the thread pool threads wait for that to finish, and then having the outer thread pool thread wait for *those* to finish.  Don't do that.  If you want to run two things in the UI thread, just run them in the UI thread, don't schedule 3 thread pool threads to sit there doing nothing while you do 2 things in the UI thread.

Comment: If I understand what you're saying, I should place the UI work inside the Dispatcher.Invoke() methods and place the timer logic outside of the Dispatcher.Invoke() call?

Comment: You shouldn't touch the UI in your background work at all.  You should very rarely, if ever, use `Dispatcher.Invoke`.  Get whatever data you need from the UI, then create some worker(s) and give them the data, have then return any result they may compute, and then update the UI after the background work has finished, with your results.

Answer (score 3):

As everyone already stated, you do your "background" work in the UI thread, as you're using the `Dispatcher` object in a wrong way. You should use it **only** for UI events. So, a couple of things you can do better in your code:

1. As you have an `async` event handler, you can use the UI-oriented code there without the `Dispatcher`, just move it out from `await` construct:

   ```
   private async void Button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
       _sw = new Stopwatch();
       _sw.Start();
       Label1.Content = "Working...";

       // save the context and return here after task is done
       await Task.Run(() =>
       {
           Parallel.Invoke(Work1, Work2);
       });
       // back on UI-context here
       UpdateLabel();
   }
   ```
2. Your "background" code uses the `Button1.Content` property, which you can get in your event handler without the `Dispatcher`, again. After that you may create a lambdas with passing your param to the background actions:

   ```
   private async void Button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
       _sw = new Stopwatch();
       _sw.Start();
       Label1.Content = "Working...";
       var buttonContent = ((Button) sender).Content
       // this will work too
       // consider to rename your button
       // var buttonContent = Button1.Content

       // save the context and return here after task is done
       await Task.Run(() =>
       {
           Parallel.Invoke(() => Work1(buttonContent),
                           () => Work2(buttonContent));
       });
       // back on UI-context here
       UpdateLabel();
   }
   ```
3. Now you can remove the `Dispatcher` again, this time you can do that in your `Work#` methods (as you do not need to get anything from UI for now):

   ```
   private void Work1(string text)
   {
       var stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
       stopWatch.Start();
       for (var i = 0; i < 100000000; i++)
       {
            // real work here
       }
       _t1 = stopWatch.Elapsed.ToString();
   }

   private void Work2(string text)
   {
       var stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
       stopWatch.Start();
       for (var i = 0; i < 100000000; i++)
       {
            // real work here
       }
       _t2 = stopWatch.Elapsed.ToString();
   }
   ```
4. Finally, you should remove the additional task creation. As `Parallel.Invoke` doesn't return a `Task`, so it can't be awaited, you should replace it with a [`Task.WhenAll`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh160374.aspx) method, like this:

   ```
   private async void Button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
       _sw = new Stopwatch();
       _sw.Start();
       Label1.Content = "Working...";
       var buttonContent = ((Button) sender).Content

       var w1 = Task.Run(() => Work1(buttonContent));
       var w2 = Task.Run(() => Work2(buttonContent));

       await Task.WhenAll(w1, w2);

       // back on UI-context here
       UpdateLabel();
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

`Dispatcher` in its essence is marshalling work to certain thread. That thread in your context most likely will be UI thread.

So what your code is doing:

1. Queues `Work1` and `Work2` to be performed on available threadpool threads.
2. In `Work1` and `Work2` you marshall work to UI thread.

Result - all computation heavy work will be performed on a single thread. Which is UI thread.

> Am I correct in assuming that the app is running the worker methods in parallel and something is forcing the app to behave in a synchronous manner?

Yes, worker methods are being ran on different threads. Also, you are correct that "something is forcing the app to behave in a synchronous manner" which is `Dispatcher.Invoke` it marshalls work to UI thread. This means that all computation heavy work being passed as a delegate will be executed on a single thread (UI thread). While Worker methods are being invoked from different thread work is being done on UI thread.

> Why am I getting the sum of the worker methods' times for the total time?

Because worker method body is being executed on a single thread.